when using npm link in the local project to use the library, the image path is incorrect. How to solve it?
Local project A is a vue project built with vite, and the npm component library B is also a vue project built with vite. Both A and B are subdirectories of the root folder.
In A, the alias "@" is used to import components of project A, while in B, the alias "$" is used to import components of project B.
Project A imports the component library B using "vue.use".
When developing and testing components of library B in project A, real-time updates are required when modifying B. Therefore, using the built files after each build is not preferred as it is inconvenient for development and testing.
Imports within component B using relative paths work fine, but using absolute paths will cause A to search for the files, resulting in errors if not found. How can I resolve the path issue?
enter image description here
The second and fifth points are still displayed in the original format. What should I do?
